# SoftLayer_Account::getOperatingSystemReloadImages

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to use API to get the available OS list during OSReload.
I found the method SoftLayer_Account::getOperatingSystemReloadImages is mentioned.But cannot find the usage about this method.
Who can help me on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find this method  `getOperatingSystemReloadImages`. But I found a way to get OS reload options:

First, we need to know the package used to order the server. For example for `Virtual Guests`, the package used is `46`. But if you want to confirm this, please execute the following `Rest` request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[vsi_id]/getBillingItem?objectMask=mask[package]

Method: GET
```

Then, to get `”Reload options”`, execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/46/getItemPrices?objectFilter={   "itemPrices": {     "categories": {       "categoryCode": {         "operation": "os"       }     }   } }&objectMask=mask[id,item[softwareDescription], categories[categoryCode]]

Method: GET
```

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getBillingItem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getBillingItem)

[SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices)

### EDIT:

Now, in order to use `” SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::reloadOperatingSystem”`, we need add some parameters in Json body configuration: “token” and “config” (Ref: [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::reloadOperatingSystem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/reloadOperatingSystem))

Below is a **REST** example:

URL:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtual_Guest_ID]/reloadOperatingSystem
```

Method: POST

Json:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    "FORCE",
    {
      "itemPrices": [
        {
          "id": 45466
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where: 45466 is the new priceId of the OS

Comment: This method is mentioned by SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::reloadOperatingSystem at below url:http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/reloadOperatingSystem. Let me also try your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @April, I added a Rest example for `"SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::reloadOperatingSystem" in `"EDIT"` section. Please review it :). I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

See this example to reload OS https://gist.github.com/softlayer/407058

Comment: Thanks. Let me test first.