# softlayer api Account can not be found in the 'getOperatingSystemReloadImages' method

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Softlayer api reference is  a method called 'getOperatingSystemReloadImages' the 'Account' services. But that did not find in the  api source development.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify where you saw a reference to getOperatingSystemReloadImages? I don't see that as an option for [Virtual_Guest](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest).

Comment: This issue might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563416/softlayer-accountgetoperatingsystemreloadimages

Answer (score 0):

Please see following question already answered to get reload options, this information could help you:

> [SoftLayer_Account::getOperatingSystemReloadImages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563416/softlayer-accountgetoperatingsystemreloadimages)
>
> https://gist.github.com/softlayer/407058

Regards.

Comment: image description check please.